# NOT LESS THAN IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Following is my sql query in which i am trying to pull only those records whose dt_dischargedt can be null or they should `NOT LESS THAN` the current date so it'll show only those patient's records who doesnot get discharged. Kindly let me know how can i modify the following query to accomplish what i have been trying to do.

```
       SELECT *
       FROM z_census
       where 
       DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%m-%Y') NOT LESS THAN DATE_FORMAT(dt_dischargedt,'%m-%Y') OR dt_dischargedt IS NULL
```

Comment: not less than is the same as `>=` (greater than or equal to)

Answer (score 6):

Why not try greater than or equal to? >= ?